# Restrict past dates in lightning-input

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, lightninginput

I would like to block my user from selecting a date that happened in the past in a lightning-input of type date.
For this I would like to use the min attribute of the type date.

This is the html code for the lightning-input :

```html
<lightning-input name="fromDate" label='From Date' type="date" min={todaysDate} onchange=dateEventHandler}
                 value={fromDate} date-style="short" required>
</lightning-input>
```

And here is the js code to get the date

```js
   get todaysDate() {
       var today = new Date();
       return today.toISOString();
   }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I select the current date :

[image]

Any Idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Once you select your current date, click outside this input, it should go away

Comment: No this is what happens after I click away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Date()** actually returns the current date time, you can see that the issue is with the time when you preview your component in the playground.

[image: LWC playground error]

Assuming you want to just restrict by the current day you need replace your todaysDate() method with something like this:

```
get todaysDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        return today
    }
```

as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/9623950

Which results in the input accepting today's date. I've left the formatting the same as in the linked example, but you can change it to whatever you require.

[image]

Comment: +1 I think the format changes according to the locality of users.

Comment: @rahulgawale strangely enough the locale changes the error message but so does the format that I return.


If I return today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
The error message will be 'Value must be 09/16/2020 or later'. for every locale.

If I return today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;

The error message is 'Value must be 16.09.2020 or later'. (for german locale).
'Value must be 16 Sep 2020 or later'. (for french and english locale).